bump react-redux issue: Super expression must either be null or a function
I upgraded the Redux and react-redux versions in the project:
1.bump Redux from 4.2.1 to 5.0.1
2.bump react-redux from 5.1.2 to 9.1.2
I have a basic Connector, custom connect, code is as follows：

export default class Connector {
    constructor(TheComponent) {
        bindThis(this);
        const that = this;
        this.name = TheComponent.name || TheComponent.displayName;

        const WrappedComponent = connect(
            this.mapStateToProps,
            this.mapDispatchToProps,
            this.mergeProps,
            {
                areStatePropsEqual: (nextStateProps, stateProps) => {
                    // this.triggerActions(this.dispatch, this.store.getState(), nextStateProps);
                    this.__propsNotChanged = this.areStatePropsEqual(nextStateProps, stateProps);
                    return this.__propsNotChanged;
                },
            }
        )(TheComponent);

        class Wrapped extends WrappedComponent {
            constructor(props, context) {
                super(props, context);
            }

            componentWillMount() {
                // dispatch actions as fast as possible
                that.triggerActions(that.dispatch, that.store.getState(), this.selector.props);
            }

            componentWillUnmount() {
                super.componentWillUnmount();
                that.__subscribtion();
            }

            componentDidMount() {
                super.componentDidMount();

            }
        }

        return Wrapped;
    }
}

This error will occur as long as you upgrade to any version above react-redux v7,I now get this error:
Super expression must either be null or a function
at _inherits (connector.js:4:75)
at eval (connector.js:146:5)
I hope to fix this error

The connect Higher Order Component is all but deprecated in modern Redux. React class components were effectively deprecated in 2019 when React hooks were released. Is there a compelling reason why you are still trying to use such outdated code and patterns? It's highly recommended you update and use modern Redux in React, e.g. the useDispatch and useSelector hooks.
